# Release Linux software to end user

Tags: linux, qt, release

I'm developping with *Qt* a multiplateform application under GPL license (here: https://github.com/Phonations/Joker). I have to release build for both *Windows* and *MacOS* platform:

- Windows release build create an installer with an [Inno setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) script
- MacOS release build create a DMG for easy drag and drop deployement

I wonder how I could make available my software to Linux end user?

I'm under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and using Qt 5.3.

Comment: interesting application Martin ;)

Comment: star it if you like!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to package your software for a limited set of distributions. Start by making a `.deb` package for your own platform (Ubuntu 14.04 for x86-64).